# ImportError: No module named 'myapp' in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have started updating a little test project for Django 1.9. My structure is as follows:

```
- myproject
- settings.py
- urls.py
- wsgi.py
- __init__.py
 - apps
 - __init__.py
  - myapp
   - admin.py
   - cms_app.py
   - cms_appconfig.py
   - models.py
   - urls.py
   - views.py
   -__init__.py
```

The Error I get is:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x1079c71e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')), )
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    urlpatterns = get_app_patterns()
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/appresolver.py", line 184, in get_app_patterns
    return _get_app_patterns()
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/appresolver.py", line 248, in _get_app_patterns
    app_ns, get_patterns_for_title(path, title), app)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/appresolver.py", line 174, in get_patterns_for_title
    for pattern_list in get_app_urls(app.get_urls(title.page, title.language)):
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/appresolver.py", line 158, in get_app_urls
    mod = import_module(urlconf)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/myproject/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Importerror: No module named 'myapp'
```

The error occured after I added a site with my app in it. 
cms_app.py:

```
# coding=utf-8
from aldryn_apphooks_config.app_base import CMSConfigApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import MyappConfig


class MyApp(CMSConfigApp):
    app_config = MyappConfig
    app_name = 'myapp'
    name = _("myapp")
    urls = ['crowdfunding.urls']

apphook_pool.register(MyApp)
```

urls.py :

```
# coding=utf-8
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from .views import ProjectListView, ProjectDetailView

Urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', ProjectListView.as_view(),
        name="project_list"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)$',
        ProjectDetailView.as_view(),
        name="project_details"),
    )
```

projects urls.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function, unicode_literals

from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import *  # NOQA
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myproject.apps.myapp'), name="myapp"),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')), )

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
            'django.views.static.serve',  # NOQA
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
             'show_indexes': True
             }), ) + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns  # NOQA
```

I have tried several things, like for example directly importing the views in the projects urls.py which then gives me the error that "apps" can not be found, which is a strange error for me. Also I removed the "name" in the projects urls.py, and looked through cms_app.py if the apps name is not correctly given (it's correct I think).

The settings.py contains my project:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    ...
    'myproject',
    'myproject.apps.myapp'
]
```

I haven't seen this error before (in Django 1.8), and currently I am thinking, that it has something to do with the urls.py(s) and the app loading. I am sure that this app worked in 1.8 but I couldn't find info about changes from 1.8 to 1.9 that would produce such an error. So I ask you please help me, find a solution.

**Update:**
I now added (according to the Django 1.9 guide) an /apps/myapp/apps.py with the following content:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.apps import AppConfig

class Myapp(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
    verbose_name = 'My App Test'
```

and in the apps/myapp/**init**.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
__version__ = '0.3'

default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.Myapp'
```

I also removed the url patterns from the main urls.py and just have it in apps/myapp/urls.py as suggested by that guide as well.

Now the error message is a bit shorter:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10975d7b8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/cr_new/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/cr_new/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/cr_new/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/cr_new/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/cr_new/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/cr_new/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/cr_new/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/cr_new/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/projects/cr_new/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'myapp'
```

I think, that it has something to do with the app loading but I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: what's apphook_pool.register(M<App) supposed to do?

Comment: Because it's an ImportError, the best way to look might be control+F for "myapp", commenting out where the module might not be recognized in a line of code. This commonly occurs in url() declarations. Also,the new standard for url imports is, `from app import views as app_views`, using `url` as follows: `url(r'regex', app_views.view)`, so, it's possible this is where myapp wasn't recognized. Your project structure is, to say the least, a bit different from what I'm used to seeing, but, if you've inspected `INSTALLED_APPS` is probably not causing the issue.

Comment: @e4c5 it's a typo during conversion I made. It's correct in the original code.

Comment: @JordonBirk I will try changing the url style. The project structure is taken from tutorials I made before (django-1.7 and 1.8) and I use it in my projects since then. So this error is really new to me.

Comment: @JordonBirk I now get what you meant, I use classy views, because they typically get more complex. This is why the url style is different. I also searched through the project but actually myapp is not imported directly anywhere.

Comment: I have no fix for this. I now restarted the project, reworked the whole thing and it works now. I can not see any difference in the code, therefore I have no idea what did the trick.